# Validation of JWT token along with requestBody parameter in springBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an reactive spring boot application where I am having different controllers and all the controller having get, post, put, delete methods
GET and DELETE method URI format => /{userName}/{others}
and it's ensured that put and post method must have a field userid in their request body.
Also All the request having an authorization header.

And I already have a method called validate that accepts 2 parameters authorizationHeader and userName and returns true if this mapping exists false if not.

I am trying to write generic filter can filter incoming request and validate before going to controller.

How can I write this generic webfilter especially how to extract body from post request and validate requests.

I tried writing this

```java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ExampleWebFilter implements WebFilter {
@Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return serverWebExchange
                .getRequest()
                .getBody()
                .next()
                .flatMap(body -> {
                    try {
                        return validate(body, serverWebExchange
                .geHeaders().get(0))
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return Mono.error(e);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap((boolean s) -> {
                    return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
                });
    }
    
    Mono<Boolean> validate(DataBuffer body, String Header){
    
    //my logic to validate 
    
    }
    
    }
```

But it seems it's hanging after this filter method executed. so my question is

1. How can I write webfilter which will read body and validate?
2. Is there any other generic solution available for this type of problem in spring-boot?

Comment: To implement JWT Authentication in Spring Boot I usually use Spring Security :  https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt

Comment: what kind of value the authorization header will have, is that a JWT?

Comment: YES it's JWT @MidhunMohan

Comment: Then just a suggestion, instead of using userId from req body,  shall we have a uid->userid claim on jwt and use that if it is valid. In this case you only need to access the header and do the needful.

But if the user id expected in API is not the token owner's id this will not work

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Interceptors. You can intercept the http call, and make your validations on the request. You can do this as global or you can do this for specific endpoints/paths. Here is a example for your case.

```
@Component
public class ProductServiceInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws 
      Exception {
  
      return true;
   }
   @Override
   public void postHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, 
      ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
      //make validations 
    }

   @Override
   public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
     Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {
      //make validations
   }
}
```

After this you need to register your interceptor like below.

```
@Component
public class ProductServiceInterceptorAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   @Autowired
   ProductServiceInterceptor productServiceInterceptor;

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(productServiceInterceptor);
   }
}
```

For more depth information you can visit the links below.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agBadIAx0Wc
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm

Comment: Actually I am using spring-boot-webflux my application is reactive so there is No HandlerInterceptor is for me. it won't work for me. there is AsyncWebRequestInterceptor but requestBody is not accessible there.